# Kafka store message details or message id

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am developing a new notification microservice using SpringBoot and Kafka. It works like this:

1. The notification service has an API where consumers can send a notification message request.
2. The notification service puts this request on a kafka queue and sends back an accepted response.
3. The notification service reads the Kafka queue and sends the notifications to an external email/SMS service.

For point 1, the message details (e.g. sender, message) are put into the kafka queue. Ideally I don't want to put all these details in the kafka message. I could insert the notification into a DB and return a notification ID which is put into the Kafka message. The only concern I have here is due to the volume of requests, I don't want to overload the DB or if there is a DB issue I lose requests.

Any advice/recommendations of what is best practice?

Comment: What are your concern putting all the details in a kafka message? Size?

Comment: It's more about data privacy. It contains personal user information.

Comment: In that case maybe encrypt it on the producer side with a public key and encrypt it with a private key on the client side ... just as an idea